# Pandas: How to select the minimum value of a series of rows grouped by a key

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

Suppose I have the followin dataframe:

```
Key | Amount | Term   | Other | Other_2
----+--------+--------+-------+--------
A   |   9999 | Short  | ABC   | 100
A   |    261 | Short  | ABC   | 100
B   |    281 | Long   | CDE   | 200
C   |    140 | Long   | EFG   | 300
C   |   9999 | Long   | EFG   | 300
```

The desired output should be:

```
Key | Amount | Term   | Other | Other_2
----+--------+--------+-------+--------
A   |    261 | Short  | ABC   | 100
B   |    281 | Long   | CDE   | 200
C   |    140 | Long   | EFG   | 300
```

That is, to take the min of the "Amount" column while retaining the rest of the values in the row with the min value.

I think this can be done with a groupby() but I don't visualize how.

**EDIT**: I removed the commas, my data is numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the min value within each key, you can use `groupby.apply` to create a boolean Series where the min value takes true and other values take false; then you can use the boolean series for subsetting:

```
df[df.Amount.groupby(df.Key).apply(lambda x: x == x.min())]

# Key   Amount   Term   Other   Other_2
#1  A      261  Short     ABC       100
#2  B      281   Long     CDE       200
#3  C      140   Long     EFG       300
```

---

Another option you can use `nsmallest()` method on each sub group, here you can take the smallest row ordered by `Amount`:

```
df.groupby("Key", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.nsmallest(1, "Amount"))

# Key   Amount   Term   Other   Other_2
#1  A      261  Short     ABC       100
#2  B      281   Long     CDE       200
#3  C      140   Long     EFG       300
```

Comment: Right... the comma was an error when I posted the question, I'll correct it, my data is clean of commas, thanks!

Comment: I'll try that in my dataframe, And try to understand how this thing works

Comment: Oh I think I got it. the x == x.min() will do true for the minimal row, thus selecting it!!

Comment: `x` is a series. x.min() calculates the minimum value in the series. `x == x.min()` will mark the minimum value as true and values larger than the minimum false. And then if you use it as indexing, rows with true values will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still have a "minor" problem, what happens if I have a NaN en in the key and it is the only row? The solution will discard it, right?

Comment: One solution (for this dataset) would be converting the NaN to an absurd  numeric 88,888,888, before applying the solution, after that returning the numeric to NaN, but I think it's too dirty and there must be some other way. I don't see that in the docs for nsmallest() or min()

Comment: Do you mean the missing value in the Key column or the Amount column, if in the Amount column, you probably can go with an if else: `df.groupby("Key", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.nsmallest(1, "Amount") if not g.Amount.isnull().all() else g.head(1))`